# Data Sanitization in PHP

Tags: php, sanitization

Can someone recommend an up to date library for data Sanitization in PHP ?

I am looking for a library that proposes a set of functions for data sanitization. Email validation/sanitization (remove those %0A, \r...), strip htlm (stripslashes(htmlentities), remove script, SQL injection … any form of exploit related to data submitted by users.

[CakePHP](http://api.cakephp.org/file/libs/sanitize.php) sanitization class (not the "framework") looks nice.. ?

Comment: Please define "data sanitization". Are you wanting to remove html entities, just potential xss attacks, or sql injection attacks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [PHP Filter](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html)

Comment: Or directly the official manual entry of PHP's Data Filtering: http://www.php.net/filter

Answer (score 1):

[Zend Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.html), [Zend Filter Input](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) and [Zend_Validate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
$firstName = $_POST['fname'];
$new_string = filter_var($firstName, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo $new_string;
```

Comment: PHP filters were already posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP is a framework, not a sanitation library.

It's probably easier to just write your own sanitization functions.

Comment: I was only going to use the sanitize.php file.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as data sanitization. Data isn't dangerous on it self - it's the context in which it's used, that makes it safe or unsafe. That means that it is pointless to try and validate/sanitize data on entry. Instead, your should escape it properly on output. See also my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php/130323#130323).

Comment: If you need to allow markup in input, but you don't want xss attacks, then it's not "pointless" to validate/sanitize data on entry. Why would you store dangerous input?

Comment: I consider that an edge case and I'd use HtmlPurifier for that.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering out xss attacks when you need to preserve html markup: [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

If you don't need to keep html markup, you can use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)