# PDO Insert with POST

Tags: php, html, forms, pdo

I currently have this type of PDO statement to INSERT variables into the array below.  I was told using PDO statements would be the most secure way of doing an insert in PHP.

```
$qry = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO twocents (path, name, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$qry->execute(array($path, $name, $message));
```

Now, would setting `$path`, `$name`, and `$message` to the POST values from a posted form still be as secure?  I'm not sure how else you would do an INSERT if those variables weren't being set by anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is completely secure in terms of SQL injections prevention.

However, you'll probably still need to escape the data on output, e.g. if `$message` you received is `<script language="Javascript" src="http://evil.site.com/evil.script.js"></script>`, you probably wouldn't want to output it with `<p><?=$message?></p>`. Some template engines (XSLT for example) eliminate this problem by separately processing HTML (XML) code and data, so that in `<p><xsl:value-of select="message"/></p>`, `message` is treated as a `<p/>` node text value, and is automatically escaped when writing a processed XML into a string.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it would probably be fine.  However, you'd probably want to perform some type of [sanitization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841152/data-sanitization-in-php) on the $_POST data before inserting it into the prepared statement.  Otherwise, you might get some gnarly data in the database.  The prepared statement does help, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is secured (from sql injection only).